# How can I effectively load multiple instances of the same python module

Tags: python, object, multiple-instances

I understand that in python modules are only ever normally instantiated once, however I would very much like to be able to achieve the same effect as instantiating the same module multiple times.

As a minimal example I have 2 files:

classes_1.py

```
class my_class:
  def __init__(self,x):
    self.pg = __import__('put_x_get_x')
    self.pg.initialise(x)
  def getx(self):
    return self.pg.extract_x()
```

main.py

```
from classes_1 import my_class
objs = []
objs.append(my_class(3.145))
print objs[0].getx()
objs.append(my_class(2.718))
print objs[0].getx()
print objs[1].getx()
```

for which running:

```
$ python main.py
```

currently outputs

```
3.145
2.718
2.718
```

But I would like it to return

```
3.145
3.145
2.718
```

Is there a way to modify the classes_1.py file to achieve this?

The reason I want to do this is that the true module I want to instantiate is actually a wrapper for a very large old fortran code. Inside the module there are thousands of variables which need to be initialised and which then alter the output of the fortran functions I want to expose to the python code. Since the initialisation of these variables is very expensive compared to the subsequent function calls, I can't afford to just reinitialise the module variables each time (particularly as I need to call the same function many millions of times). Any alternative suggestions for how to achieve this ultimate goal would also be appreciated.

Comment: `import` in Python is close to `ClassLoader` in Java. In java, you can write your own class loader but in Python, I'm pretty sure you can't specialize import ...